# Golang Swagger Docs Generate Snake Case instead of CamelCase parameter names

Tags: json, go, swagger

I am generating some swagger docs using openapiv2_swagger plugin and but the parameters that we are generating all use the snake case format that the go protos are defined as. How do I configure swagger to show the protos in the CamelCase format.

I've tried setting the response to something like this

```
  `key: "404"
    value {
      description: "Not Found"
      schema: {
        json_schema: {
          type: STRING;
        }
      }`
```